# Maven compile error with using Java Generics

Tags: java, maven, generics

Im using Java 8 and have the following code:

```
public WeatherDTO(Map<?,?> mappedJsonData) {
    if (mappedJsonData == null || mappedJsonData.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    List<?> weather = (List<?>)mappedJsonData.get("weather");
    if (weather != null && !weather.isEmpty()) {
        this.weather = (String) ((Map<?,?>)weather.get(0)).get("description");
    }

    Map<?,?> jsonMain = (Map<?,?>)mappedJsonData.get("main");
    if (jsonMain != null && !jsonMain.isEmpty()) {
        this.temperature = (double)jsonMain.get("temp") - 273.0;
        this.humidity = (int)jsonMain.get("humidity");
    }
}
```

This code works fine when im running the web app within Eclipse and embedded Tomcat. There is also no Problem shown in Eclipse Problems view.

But when im starting a maven compile from my shell/bash im getting the following error:

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/src/main/java/xxx/xxx/xxx/weather/WeatherDTO.java:[52,64] incompatible types: capture#1 of ? cannot be converted to double

[ERROR] /home/xxx/xxx/xxx/src/main/java/xxx/xxx/xxx/weather/WeatherDTO.java:[53,58] incompatible types: capture#2 of ? cannot be converted to int

Does anybody have a idea what im doing wrong?
The maven compiler plugin seems to be up to date and my JAVA_HOME points to a Java 8 version.

Snippet from the pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <showWarnings>false</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>false</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Configuration of java.version is 1.8; Maven is 3.0.4.

Comment: I would use `(Double)` and `(Integer)`. Quite strange to use generics and have wildcards and casts everywhere though.

Comment: I took this from a example where it was shown how to convert/map json data with jackson. There might be a mistake as im not really strong in using Generics...

Comment: Try `((double)jsonMain.get("temp")) - 273.0`.

Comment: Your `jsonMain` is a `Map<?,?>`, which is effectively `Map<Object, Object>`. When you call `jsonMain.get("temp")` it is returning to you an `Object`, which you *cannot* cast to a `double`. You could probably cast it to a `Double`, though.

Comment: I was trying to cast them into Integer and Double and it works now. But why Eclipse and embedded Tomcat have no problems. Is there a different handling of autoboxing or something like this?

Comment: Jackson is not only a JSON parser. It's also a JSON to Java object mapper. You should define Java objects which have the same structure as the JSON, and use type-safe code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the same error as you. But the following code fixes it. I've made the code a method instead of a constructor, but I think you can ignore that, eh?

```
private String weather;
private double temperature;
private int humidity;
public void WeatherDTO(Map<?, ?> mappedJsonData) {
    if (mappedJsonData == null || mappedJsonData.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    List<?> weather = (List<?>) mappedJsonData.get("weather");
    if (weather != null && !weather.isEmpty()) {
        this.weather = (String) ((Map<?, ?>) weather.get(0)).get("description");
    }

    Map<?, ?> jsonMain = (Map<?, ?>) mappedJsonData.get("main");
    if (jsonMain != null && !jsonMain.isEmpty()) {
        this.temperature = (Double) jsonMain.get("temp") - 273.0;
        this.humidity = (Integer) jsonMain.get("humidity");
    }
}
```

Comment: Casting into Objects instead primitive types fixes it indeed. But still no clue why only Maven compile has a problem with it but not my ide. Strange somehow....

Answer (score 3):

It works with objects instead of primitive types.